# How do I use two versions of Electron on the same machine

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, npm-install

When I first started to learn Election the book I was using recommended that it be installed using npm install -g electron. Now I read on the npm website that npm install electron --save-dev is the preferred way to install it.

So I created a new project directory and ran npm init then ran
npm install electron --save-dev. According to package.json Electron 1.7.5 was installed, but when I type electron in the project directory it reports version 1.6.10 which is the version that was installed with the -g option.

Is there a way to get my new project to use 1.7.5? I have already completed a small project using version 1.6.10 and don't want to do anything that would keep it from running.

Thanks,  Jim

Answer (score 0):

You can run the local version of electron out of the `node_modules/.bin` directly -- most likely it will be called `node_modules/.bin/electron`.

You can use `npm` or `gulp` (or even a shellscript/batch file) to run the app for you.

Comment: I have no node_modules/bin directory. I have a node_modules/electron/dist

Comment: Note: Above comment sent accidentally.  I have no node_modules/bin directory. I have a node_modules/electron/dist directory which seems to be the only one with an electron executable in it. If I run electron from there I get version 1.6.10 which is the global one.

Comment: @Cleanman2 Oops, had a typo in my answer above.  It is `node_modules/.bin` (note the `.`)

Comment: Ok I have an electron in the .bin directory, but when I type electron from that directory I still get a window opening that says 1.6.10. Here is the electron line from my package.json file.  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^1.7.5"
  } I think I will move my two projects out of the way and completely uninstall electron, then just reinstall the local version and see what happens. Thanks for your help.  Jim

Comment: Are you running wih a `.\electron` (windows) or `./electron` (unix)?

Comment: ./electron  I am running linux.  (Mint 18)